# NAS report on fast ignition

Tags: fusion, specific-reference

I'm looking for a paper, or much more likely a small part of a large report, by the National Academy of Sciences from around 2013 on the topic of fusion. The report mentions the fast ignition approach and that they did not see this as a practical approach. Does anyone have a pointer? That's literally all I have to go on.

Comment: Googling "fast ignition fusion 2012 national academy of sciences" turns up several links that might be what you're looking for.  Note the "2012".

Comment: No, the one I'm looking for is later. The 2012 status was still "go for it", the one I'm looking for was more "nail in coffin".

Comment: Is it possible that the report was by the NNSA, not the NAS? If so: http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2017/ph241/watson1/docs/na-0040.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, further Googling [turned it up](https://www.nap.edu/read/18288/chapter/2#5):

CONCLUSION 4-5: At this time, fast ignition appears to be a less promising approach for IFE than other ignition concepts.